# Hazelcast, check if particular key is available in hazel cast map which is configured with mapLoader(read through)

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We have implemented read-through using MapLoader with load key functionality which loads specific keys and value from database to Hazelcast map as a part of read-through. My question is if We want check if particular key is available in hazelcast map, how can I achieve that without read-through?

we tried using IMap.contains(key), but Hazelcast performs read-through and loads the data via MapLoader when key is not available. which we do not want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `IMap.getEntryView(key)`, which doesn't invoke read-through.

If you're on a newer version of Hazelcast and have SQL, you can also do:

`SELECT * FROM map WHERE __key LIKE 'key%'`